# Script to process data from database with queue

Tags: php

I want to make a PHP script to process data in the database with queue. I can do it myself, but I want to make my website do it automatically.

For example, I have two sets of data in the database, and I want my website to process the first data, and then process the second data.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use a website for this, use a `cron` job or some background process.  A website is a simple request/response system, it shouldn't be handling background tasks.

Comment: What do you mean by process? What kind of data? are we talking about a SQL-like database function?

Comment: In database level perhaps you can lockdown a process with `TRANSACTIONS` to make sure that the other process won't interrupt. 
But if it is not just two process and you want your code keep continue more and more processes in background the solution is `cron`. Basically it's like running a `bash` on the server (but in php if you want).

Comment: oh, so I must use a cron job to do process in background? thank's for reply.